# unable to call global variables inside a function class

Tags: php, class, global-variables

I am new to PHP5 and classes, am struggling with being able to get global variable to work when inside a function, to better explain it please check the code bellow.

```
class alpha{

#first function
public function n_one(){

    #variable
    $varr = 1;

    #inner function
    function n_two(){
        global $varr;

        #Unable to get variable
        echo $varr;
        if($varr)
        {
            echo 'yessssss';
        }
    }

    echo $varr // Returns variable fine
}
}
```

I seem to be doing something wrong violating how classes and functions work, can't figure what is it.

Comment: inner function? move that elsewhere.

Comment: If it's a closure or similar, try `funtion() use() {}` syntax - http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php example #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the 'inner function', and the property.

```
class Alpha
{
    private $varr = 1;

    public function n_one()
    {
        // to access a property ore another method, do this
        $this->varr = $this->doSomething();

        return $this->varr; // Returns variable fine
    }

    private function doSomething()
    {
        // manipulate $this->varr here
    }
}
```

Also, don't ever echo from within the class, instead return the variable and echo it.

```
echo $alpha->n_one();
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand it better now, I see how nested functions is not the best option, I will have to make modifications to my code.

Answer (score 0):

`global` means to access the variable in the global scope, not just the containing scope. When you refer to `$varr` in the inner function it's treated as `$GLOBALS['varr']`.

If you want it to refer to the same variable as in the outer function you need to declare the variable `global` there as well. Otherwise it's a local variable in that function, while the inner function accesses the global variable.

```
#first function
public function n_one(){
    global $varr;
    #variable
    $varr = 1;

    #inner function
    function n_two(){
        global $varr;

        #Unable to get variable
        echo $varr;
        if($varr)
        {
            echo 'yessssss';
        }
    }

    echo $varr // Returns variable fine
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `use()` declaration to declare a variable that should be inherited from the outer scope.

```
    #inner function
    function n_two() use($varr) {
        global $varr;

        #Unable to get variable
        echo $varr;
        if($varr)
        {
            echo 'yessssss';
        }
    }
```